# Empty object returns false on checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dom

I am trying to check if a div exists or not in the DOM:

```
$("#mydiv") //returns []
$.isEmptyObject($("#mydiv")) //returns false
$.isEmptyObject([]) //returns true
```

Any idea what might I be doing wrong?
Also, what is the best way of checking existence of an element in DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isEmptyObject` isn't used to check if the object contains other objects. It is used to check whether the object has properties.

`$.isEmptyObject($("#mydiv"))` returns false because there are lots of properties that you can call on this object

```
$("#mydiv").html()
$("#mydiv").text()
// etc
```

As others have said, if you are trying to see if the object exists in the DOM, use the `length` property

Answer (score 5):

Check with `.length` in jquery

```
if($("#mydiv").length > 0)
```

or

```
if($(document).find("#mydiv").length > 0)
```

Comment: OP is asking why didn't his code working..? Any ideas on that, it would help us learning about `$.isEmptyObject()` Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works properly. But any idea why didn't the other one work? Seems equivalent, but apparently it isn't

Comment: Oh my god, the second one does not make any sense, simple id selector is enogh for that..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - The OP asks  check if a div exists or not in the DOM:

Comment: I mainly ask what I'm doing wrong above :) Maybe I should correct something if it's misleading, but I'd really want to know why doesn't it work the way I did it